# MSBuild error opening vs2017 csproj files (The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized...)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm experiencing the following error:

```
The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0", "14.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".  C:\....\Sol.csproj
```

Excpetion from this piece of code:

```
using(Evaluation.ProjectCollection col = new Evaluation.ProjectCollection())
{
   Evaluation.Project def = col.LoadProject(filename);
}
```

Dll is: Microsoft.Build version 15.1

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 15.3.4, this didn't happens before with 15.2

I already look for [microsoft github #2369](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2369)

**MSBuild Version:** Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Framework

Comment: There are a lot of msbuild versions around lately, you'll have to document which one you use.  VS2017 has yet another special one, it is awfully hard to find back.  Well, surely the underlying issue.  I think the approach today is to never rely on installed versions but only ever on Nuget packages.  Hard to find btw, too many hits.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thank you in advance. This the version: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Framework

Comment: Erm, you are using the msbuild api, not msbuild.exe.  Use the debugger's Debug > Windows > Modules window, it shows you where the DLLs came from.

Comment: api cames from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll

Comment: That's in the ball-park.  It sounds very similar to [this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97148/the-tools-version-150-is-unrecognized-and-database.html), also the site where you might get help.  I'm hearing a lot of complaints about 15.3 and have avoided updating.

Comment: Hi Hans, ok... will try to do that. Is there anyway to get back 15.2?

Comment: @HLourenco, you could not find a way to do that. You have to uninstall VS 2017 15.3 completely and install VS 2017 15.0 from this link:https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=2210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fix that problem some months ago.

I notice that Microsoft release a "break" in dll (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation) and fix that following some explanations, for example: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95732/microsoftbuildevaluation-api-is-broken-since-the-r.html

Thank you all